# many to one sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have 3 tables that I need to file to a single row by row information that is based on headers, questions, response. They are all related by Foreign Keys.

the TABLES looks like this:

```
Headers
ID    TemplateID
0         9
1         8
2         7

Questions
------------------
ID   |  TemplateID
-------------------
0           9
1           9
2           8
3           8
4           8
5           7
6           7

-----------------
Response
-----------------
ID      HeaderID
0           0       
1           0
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           2
6           2

And I want my Query to return it like this
HeaderID    TemplateID      QuestionID1     ResponseID1     QuestionID2     ResponseID2     QuestionID3     ResponseID3
0               9               0               0               1               0               Null            Null
1               8               2               2               3               2               4               2
2               7               5               5               6               6               Null            Null
```

I'm new to SQL, and have tried every Join that I know and don't know if this is possible or not. I hope that the information I posted Helps in solving my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Lookup pivot. Also, you should handle this in your application code.

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The question has all the data but what have you tried? if you have no idea, please refer some documentation.[here is an example](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-hveZ8-7RAhWKpI8KHfz5B6EQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fsql%2Fsql_join.asp&usg=AFQjCNFZqxeBfoVWkdNQwzQdaJxwbVJwuQ&bvm=bv.145822982,d.c2I)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.TemplateID, b.ID, c.ID, b2.ID, c2.ID, b3.ID, c3.ID
FROM Headers a LEFT JOIN Questions b ON a.ID=b.ID LEFT JOIN 
Response C ON b.ID=C.ID LEFT JOIN Questions b2 ON b2.ID = c.ID 
LEFT JOIN Response c2 ON b2.ID = c2.ID 
LEFT JOIN Questions b3 ON c2.ID = b3.ID LEFT JOIN Response c3 ON b3.ID = c3.ID
```

Is how I interpret your questions. Just do enough left joins that you "capture" the maximum amount of ID.s